# What does the Kaldheim Commander expansion symbol represent?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

What does the Kaldheim Commander expansion symbol represent?

https://mtg.fandom.com/wiki/Kaldheim/Commander_decks

https://scryfall.com/sets/khc

Comment: Not sure why people downvote. Obviously this information is not available in wikipedia, gamepedia and and WotC site. Please advice what I am doing wrong. Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Kaldheim Commander's symbol simply represents a shield. That's tradition at this point: Commander decks have been using vaguely shield-like abstract designs since Commander 2013 or 2014 (depending on how you read them), as is visible from [Scryfall's list of Commander sets](https://scryfall.com/sets?type=commander).

They don't tend to represent anything in specific, but recent Commander sets released alongside standard products have something hinting at the set they're contemporary with: Midnight Hunt Commander has a claw slash across the shield; Forgotten Realms Commander has a dragon on the shield; Kaldheim Commander's shield has an additional symbol that appears to hint at the labrys (double-sided axe) used for the Kaldheim set symbol.